With glTexStorage3D why cant i allocate more than 2048 2D texures and what do I do if i need more?
While using glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, GL_RGBA8, width, height, depth); I can't set depth more than 2048 (otherwise OpenGL drops 1281 error which is GL_INVALID_VALUE), but I didn't found any info about this very limit.
I found out that this should be limited by GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS which is 35071 in glew.h file. On docs.gl or Khronos Registry there is nothing said about depth's limits and it only says

GL_INVALID_VALUE is generated if width, height, depth or levels are less than 1.

which is deftenetly not.
Where can I find information about this limit and what do I do if i need to allocate more than 2048 textures in a texture array?

GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS = 35071 is not the max value, it's a enum constant. Pass it to glGetIntegerv.

"what do I do if i need to allocate more than 2048 textures in a texture array?" Allocate other arrays? You can bind and use more than one texture in a shader, no?

I want to use batch rendering which means that i can't use more then one texture array because i can't bind another texture array in the middle of the draw call
